# Find file (get content) with variable in file name

Tags: powershell, variables, batch-file, parameters

I wanted to make a small script for finding and replacing several strings in a file (using a combination of batch and PowerShell). The files are always different, so I'd always need to go into the batch and change the file name of `Get-Content` and of `Out-File`.
Now I added a prompt to insert the filename and I'm giving this to a parameter, so I could somehow search and edit `$filename.txt` for example.

Here the normal PowerShell code with replacing just one string (I'll integrate this in one batch file later again):

```
$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input filename'
(gc $filename.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File $filename.txt
```

Since this Script is lying in the same folder like the files I'm not gonna need a path.

I also found out that `gc` can't read variables, which is exactly my problem here: I'm getting an error code that the argument can't be bound to "path" because it's NULL.

I couldn't find anything else like that, found a lot of Threads on how to out-file variables or how to get file content *into* a variable but nothing fitting to my case so I'd really appreciate any help from you guys!

Comment: I don't understand why you need both batch and PowerShell. If you are working in PowerShell, then I think you would be best served to ditch the batch. If you want to work with batch, then you might consider my [JREPL.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). You could use SET /P to prompt for a value for a FileName variable. Then you could simply use `call jrepl "foo" "bar" /L /F '%FileName%" /O -`

Comment: I think I already found this Batch but I was getting very confused with all the content haha, so I’d actually just need to add this part at the very end?
I knew about this /P option but I tried to use this together with powershell in one batch and that didn’t work.
Powershell because people kept saying: since powershell is preinstalled rather use this instead of batch.
Maybe because like with your batch I need a lot of coding for making a batch work just as simple as powershell.

I wanted to integrate it in batch, for friends to use it, too. So I need it to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell allows you to use one-word strings or a variable without putting them quotes, so the following two statements will work:

```
Get-Content foo.txt
Get-Content $filename
```

However, if you want to use an argument that's constructed of a variable and a string you need to put the expression in double quotes:

```
Get-Content "$filename.txt"
```

or use a subexpression for concatenating variable and string:

```
Get-Content ($filename + '.txt')
```

With that said, since in your case you're using the filename in more than one place it's probably best to append the extension to your input and use just a variable:

```
$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input filename'
$filename += '.txt'
(Get-Content $filename) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Set-Content $filename
```

Comment: Powershell file (working):
`$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input filename'
(gc "$filename.c4d") -replace 'foo', 'bar'| Set-Content "$filename.c4d"`

Batch file with Powershell integrated:
@ECHO OFF
powershell -Command "$filename = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input filename'; (gc "$filename.c4d") -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Set-Content "$filename.c4d"`
Also: is Set-Content more accurate? I noticed Out-File kinda broke my file (.c4d) so the program could not read it anymore.

Comment: @Shoru Just drop the batch file and run the PowerShell script by itself. Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` once first if you haven't done that already. It's pointless (and error-prone, as you can see) to use batch as a wrapper for PowerShell. As for `Set-Content`: it's not "more accurate", it just uses ASCII as the default encoding whereas `Out-File` uses Unicode (which probably is the reason why your program couldn't read the file).

Comment: My first comment wasn't sent for some reason: The `$filename += '.txt'` is working like a charm even within batch! Thanks for that. I was only wondering why it wouldnt work with double quotes, since its the same code. And for your tips in the first post: I tried `$filename += '.txt'` earlier before, but I think I forgot the single quotes, so it didn't work. :) And ok I didn't really think or consider the differences in ASCII and Unicode encoding.

Comment: @Shoru It doesn't work with double quotes, because the command string is in double quotes as well, so the nested double quotes prematurely terminate that string. You need to double nested double quotes to avoid this. Or avoid wrapping PowerShell code in batch files altogether, which is what I'd recommend.